# Как грамотно реализовать стейт в приложении React-Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, redux, redux-thunk

Всем доброго времени суток. Делаю простое приложение на React-Redux, опыта  с React немного. Столкнулся со странной структурой стейта приложения. Привожу исходный код.
Actions:

```
export const actionView = (_view) => {
  return {
    type: 'VIEW', view: _view,
  }
};

export const actionDel = (_id) => {
  return {
    type: 'DEL', id: _id
  }
};

export const actionEdit = (_id, _spec) => {
  return {
    type: 'EDIT', id: _id, spec: _spec
  }
};

export const actionAdd = (_spec) => {
  return {
    type: 'ADD', spec: _spec
  }
};

export const actionType = (_scanCode) => {
  return { type: 'TYPE', scanCode: _scanCode }
};

export const actionSetSpec = _spec => {
  return { type: 'SET_SPEC', spec: _spec }
};

export function performView() {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    let Resp = service.view();
    dispatch(actionView(Resp));
  }
}

export function performDel(id) {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    service.del(id);
    dispatch(actionDel(id));
  }
}

export function performEdit(id, spec) {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    service.edit(id, spec);
    dispatch(actionEdit(id, spec));
  }
}

export function performAdd(spec) {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    service.add(spec);
    dispatch(actionAdd(spec));
  }
}
```

Исходник с редьюсерами:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import Immutable from 'seamless-immutable';
const iniState = Immutable({ view: [], shift: false, lang: 'en', caps: false, spec: '', scanCode: 0 });

export function view(state = iniState, action = {}) {
  let newState;
  if (action.type === 'VIEW') {
    newState = state.merge({ view: action.view });
    return newState;
  } else {
    return iniState;
  }
};

export function del(state = iniState, action = {}) {
  let newState;
  if (action.type === 'DEL') {
    newState = state.merge({ id: action.id });
    return newState;
  } else {
    return iniState;
  }
}

export function add(state = iniState, action = {}) {
  let newState;
  if (action.type === 'ADD') {
    newState = state.merge({ spec: action.spec });
    return newState;
  } else {
    return iniState;
  }
}

export function edit(state = iniState, action = {}) {
  let newState;
  if (action.type === 'EDIT') {
    newState = state.merge({ id: action.id, spec: action.spec });
    return newState;
  } else {
    return iniState;
  }
}

export function setSpec(state = iniState, action = {}) {
  let newState;
  if (action.type === 'SET_SPEC') {
    newState = state.merge({ spec: action.spec });
    return newState;
  } else {
    return iniState;
  }
}

export function type(state = iniState, action = {}) {
  let newState;
  if (action.type === 'TYPE') {
    if (action.scanCode > 0) {
      newState = state.merge({ spec: state.spec + Symbol(action.scanCode).toString() });
    } else {
      newState = state.merge({ scanCode: action.scanCode });
    }
    return newState;
  } else {
    return iniState;
  }
}
export default combineReducers({ view, del, edit, add, type, setSpec });
```

Привожу метод Render одного из компонентов:

```
render() {
  let view = this.props.view;
  console.log(view);
...
 }

  const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
   view: state,
   scanCode: state.scanCode
   }
}
```

В консоли вижу:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне неясно, почему такая странная структура стейта, с вложенными объектами соответственно reducers. Возможно что-то не так делаю. Спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Стейт так выглядит потому что так работает combine reducers - он разбивает стейт на несколько кусков, каждый из которых обрабатывается своим редьюсером. Вы, похоже, хотите выстроить редьюсеры в цепочку, чтобы action проходил через них по очереди,  и чтобы на выходе получался стецт, пропущенный через все редьюсеры. Это делается через https://www.npmjs.com/package/reduce-reducers.